# What are the nuisances of creating a bootable Windows 7 USB drive from linux with ms-sys or dd?

Tags: windows-7, linux, bootable-media, usb-flash-drive

I have been reading some web pages and posts (here and in other forums) about how to create a Windows 7 installation USB media from linux (to install Windows 7)

I asked in TechNet about this, and I got a reply with general information on how to do it:

> "I personally am not very familiar with
>   linux, but basicaly all that you need
>   to do... in whatever way you do it is
>   the following:
>
> 1. Format a usb flash drive, either fat32
>      or ntfs create a partition that is
>      large enough to host the windows
>      installation (give or take 3GB for
>      64bit, aroudn 2.5gb for 32bit) and
>      mark that partition as
>      active/bootable. Since this can be
>      done with windows, but just as well
>      with a tool like gparted, you should
>      be able to do the same in debian.
> 2. Once you have created that partition,
>      mount the iso that you download, and
>      copy all files starting from the root,
>      into the root of the usb flash drive.
>
> That's all there's to it."

I found another method in various places, that is almost the same what was mentioned at TechNet. However, there seems to be a missing step in this method and/or a step that I'm not sure is necessary.

`dd` doesn't always work. Basically, the missing step was to write a proper boot sector to the usb stick, which can be done from linux with `ms-sys`. This works with the retail version of `Windows 7`.

Here is the complete rundown, [see serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/6714/how-to-make-windows-7-usb-flash-install-media-from-linux) for more details:

1. Install [ms-sys](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/).
2. Check what device your usb media is assigned ( `fdisk -l` ) here we will assume it is `/dev/sdb`.
3. Delete all partitions, create a new one taking up all the space, set type to NTFS, and set it bootable:

   `cfdisk /dev/sdb`
4. Create NTFS filesystem:

   `mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb1`
5. Mount iso and usb media:

   `mount -o loop win7.iso /mnt/iso`
   `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb`
6. Copy over all files:

   `# cp -r /mnt/iso/* /mnt/usb/`
7. Write Windows 7 MBR on usb stick:

   `# ms-sys -7 /dev/sdb`
8. Make sure the write is flushed (be patient it can take a few minutes):

   `# sync`
9. open gparted, select the USB drive, right-click on the file system, then click on "Manage Flags". Check the 'boot' checkbox, then close

...and you're done.

#### Questions

- Shouldn't the usb work without doing the last step `# ms-sys -7 /dev/sdb` ? Or is it to make the usb bootable? Does it only to mark the partition as bootable?
- Wouldn't it be better use rsync instead of `cp -r` ?
- Do all this steps have to be done as `root`? If not, do I need to `chmod` all files to `664` and `chown` all the directories that are used to mount the USB device and the ISO image? I suppose that it's just easier to copy the data as `root` and it not affect the data.
- Has anyone tried this method or some similar like copying the iso with `dd` ?

Comment: I used dd with an iso although not for windows 7. You can check to see if this works: http://superuser.com/questions/591234/creating-a-bootable-usb-from-command-line-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with dd (dd if=/file/win7.iso of=/dev/sdb), and it doesn't work.

My steps to make it work:

- Install ms-sys
- gparted to create partition, and create NTFS filesystem.

Afterwards apply these commands:

```
# mount -o loop win7.iso /mnt/iso 
# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
# cp -r /mnt/iso/* /mnt/usb/*
# ms-sys -7 /dev/sdb*
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ms-sys` command is important. With the `-7` option it **creates a Windows 7 compatible boot sector** on your flash drive.

You can't use dd because ISO's use an ISO Filesystem such as **UDF** or **ISO9660**, where-as your USB drive only properly supports disk file systems such as **ext3, FAT32, or NTFS**

> Would be better use rsync instead of cp -r ?

Not really. `cp -r` works perfectly fine. Just realize that NTFS handles permissions differently to Linux, so using rsync to keep everything intact doesn't matter too much. All that really matters is that **the files from the ISO are on the USB** and that **the boot sector is formatted correctly using `ms-sys -7`**

You can do all the steps as root if you want. The only 2 steps that really require root are `mkfs` and the 2 `mount`'s

If you're getting permission problems even as root, you may need to mount your USB using `ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1` as some Linux Distributions only supply a Read-Only driver for NTFS.