# How can I create a bootable USB of Microsoft SBS 2011 from an ISO in ubuntu 64 bit?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, windows-sbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a Windows 7 installation usb media from linux ? (to install Windows 7) - Help need to know better method](https://superuser.com/questions/256869/how-to-create-a-windows-7-installation-usb-media-from-linux-to-install-windows)

Right so Im having a bit of a mare!

I am trying to install `Mircosoft Small Business Server 2011` on a `HP Prolaint DL385` which only has a cd-rom drive. So the answer I thought was to create a bootable usb stick from the ISO using the [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool)

The problem is that I dont have Windows 7 64 Bit on which to make the bootable USB.

**The 64 bit question**: 
Can I create a bootable USB of the ISO in a 64 bit version of Ubuntu? (Which I could download) If so, how....

Comment: Or as an alternative, can anyone suggest a better way...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Windows 7 installation usb media from linux ? (to install Windows 7) - Help need to know better method](http://superuser.com/questions/256869/how-to-create-a-windows-7-installation-usb-media-from-linux-to-install-windows) and/or [Creating a Windows installation flash drive in linux](http://superuser.com/questions/315187/is-it-possible-to-create-a-windows-installation-usb-from-linux)

Comment: if you mount the iso using daemon or similar - you can just copy the files for sbs 2011 on to the usb. you dont need to mark it as bootable.