# How to create a bootable USB flash drive from a bootable DVD (for an EFI system, under Linux or Mac OS)?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, dvd, dd

There are many similar questions already, but many concern only Windows 7 and answers suggest steps to follow under Windows with some Windows tools, in others some specialized tools like UNetbootin are recommended, or the question concerns not a DVD but an ISO image.  In any case, I could not figure out yet how to do such a seemingly simple task with basic Linux tools, and why I can make a bootable USB drive with `dd` command from a downloaded ISO image, but cannot do the same from a bootable DVD.  I am looking for basic solutions and an explanation of what is going on.

I have found out that a simple `dd` command like

```
sudo dd if=/path-to/some-linux.iso of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1048576
```

works for me to create a bootable USB drive (`disk1`) for an EFI system from a downloaded ISO image of NixOS or Ubuntu.  (I am doing this under Mac OS.)  However, doing

```
sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk1 of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1048576
```

where `disk1` is a bootable Linux Mint or Windows 7 DVD and `disk2` is the USB drive does not create a bootable USB drive. Moreover, a USB drive created in this way can be mounted and explored under Mac OS, but bootable USB drives created from ISO images are not readable under Mac OS.

Can anyone explain to me, please, why `dd` does not work here directly from DVD to USB flash drive?  Is there some simple (preferably commande-line) solution?

P.S. Initially I needed to make a bootable Windows 7 USB from a recovery DVD without access to any other Windows machine, but it turned out that I cannot make a bootable USB from a Linux Mint bootable DVD either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a bootable USB from a bootable ISO with the command line on Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/591234/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-from-a-bootable-iso-with-the-command-line-on-linux)

Comment: Not exactly: there the OP talks about an ISO image, not about a DVD. I will try to look into the `isohybrid` program, however.